# Getting error for Test class for Batch apex callout (Batch chaining)

Tags: apex, unit-test, integration, servicecloud

I am writing a test class for Batch A And B Im calling Batch B from A in finish method. I am not able to invoke B Batchclass  from A. please suggest a appropriate test class

Batch apex A

```
global class clsPACaseBulkAPIJobMonitoringBatchable Implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.AllowsCallouts, Database.Stateful{
    Integer count = 0;
    global static Id idAPIIntegrationUser = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Profile.Name = 'API Integration' AND Name  = 'PremierGOSL apiintegration'].Id;
    
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
     return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM PA_Acceleration_Case_Filter__c WHERE PA_Status__c = 'Completed' AND CreatedById =:idAPIIntegrationUser AND LastModifiedById =:idAPIIntegrationUser order by LastModifiedDate desc LIMIT 1]);
    }
    
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<PA_Acceleration_Case_Filter__c> scope) {
        system.debug('### ACF Size :'+scope.Size());
        
        Map<Id, Integer> ACFSuccededCount = new Map<Id, Integer>();
        
        List<Case> CaseList = [SELECT Id,PA_Acceleration_Case_Filter__c,PA_RCID__c,Status, PA_Fiscal_Year__c, PA_Fiscal_Quarter__c, CreatedDate FROM Case WHERE PA_Acceleration_Case_Filter__c IN : scope ];
        System.debug('## CaseList Size'+CaseList.Size());   
        
        for(Case objCase : CaseList){
            if(!ACFSuccededCount.containsKey(objCase.PA_Acceleration_Case_Filter__c)){
                ACFSuccededCount.put(objCase.PA_Acceleration_Case_Filter__c, 0);
            }
            ACFSuccededCount.put(objCase.PA_Acceleration_Case_Filter__c,ACFSuccededCount.get(objCase.PA_Acceleration_Case_Filter__c)+1 );
        }
                
        List<PA_Acceleration_Case_Filter__c> ACFList = [SELECT Id,PA_Records_Failed__c,Records_Succeeded__c,PA_Total_Records_Processed__c FROM PA_Acceleration_Case_Filter__c WHERE Id IN :ACFSuccededCount.KeySet()];
        
        for(PA_Acceleration_Case_Filter__c objAcf : ACFList){
            objAcf.Records_Succeeded__c = ACFSuccededCount.get(objAcf.Id);
            objAcf.PA_Records_Failed__c = objAcf.PA_Total_Records_Processed__c - objAcf.Records_Succeeded__c;
        }
        
        Database.update (ACFList,false);
        system.debug('## I am in clsPAPostCasesToMwBatchable execute');
        
        
        
    }
    
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        system.debug('#ValueofCount='+count);
            clsPAPostCasesToMwBatchable cls = new clsPAPostCasesToMwBatchable();
            Database.executeBatch(cls);
        
    } 
}
```

Batch Apex B

```
global class clsPAPostCasesToMwBatchable implements Database.Batchable<SObject>,Database.AllowsCallouts, Database.Stateful{
   
    public static DateTime tokenExpiryDateTime = Premier_API_Token__c.getInstance(UserInfo.getOrganizationId()).Token_Expiry_DT__c;
    public static Premier_API_Token__c premierAPITokenCS = Premier_API_Token__c.getInstance(UserInfo.getOrganizationId());
    public static boolean tokenchanged = false; 
    
    global static Id idAPIIntegrationUser = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Profile.Name = 'API Integration' AND Name  = 'PremierGOSL apiintegration'].Id;
    global Id acfId = [SELECT Id from PA_Acceleration_Case_Filter__c WHERE PA_Status__c = 'Completed' AND Records_Succeeded__c > 0 AND CreatedById =: idAPIIntegrationUser AND LastModifiedById =:idAPIIntegrationUser order by LastModifiedDate desc LIMIT 1].Id;  
    
    List<Case> CaseList = new List<Case>(); 

    
    
    public static Boolean runningInASandbox {
        get {
            if (runningInASandbox == null) {
                runningInASandbox = [SELECT IsSandbox FROM Organization LIMIT 1].IsSandbox;
            }
            return runningInASandbox;
        }
        set; 
    }
    
    public static string premierAPIAccessToken {
        get {
            if( tokenExpiryDateTime < Datetime.now() && tokenchanged == false){
                premierAPIAccessToken = ReturnAccessToken();
                premierAPITokenCS.Token__c = premierAPIAccessToken;
                premierAPITokenCS.Token_Generated_DT__c = Datetime.now();
                premierAPITokenCS.Token_Expiry_DT__c = Datetime.now().addSeconds(3600);
                tokenchanged = true;
                system.debug('Token Changed');
            }else{
                premierAPIAccessToken = Premier_API_Token__c.getInstance(UserInfo.getOrganizationId()).Token__c;
                system.debug('Existing Token');
            }
            return premierAPIAccessToken;
        }
        set;
    }
    
    public class deserializeResponse{
        public String id;
        public String access_token;
    }
    
    
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        system.debug('###DisplayAcfId= '+acfId);
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id,PA_RCID__c,PA_Fiscal_Year__c,PA_Fiscal_Quarter__c,CreatedDate,PA_Acceleration_Case_Filter__c 
                                         FROM Case 
                                         WHERE PA_Acceleration_Case_Filter__c =: acfId]);
    }
    
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Case> lstCases){
        
        
        if(!lstCases.isEmpty()){
            for (Case objCse : lstCases) {
                CaseList.add(objCse);   
            }
            processCaseList();
            System.debug('##CaseListsize'+caseList.size());
            
        }
    }
    
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {  
    
    }
    
    
    public static String ReturnAccessToken (){
        //Variables declaration
        String clientId='';
        String clientSecret='';
        String endPoint='';
        String requestbody='';
        
        if ( !runningInASandbox ) {
            system.debug('*** Production ***');
            clientId = Premier_API_Production__c.getInstance(UserInfo.getOrganizationId()).Client_ID__c;
            clientSecret = Premier_API_Production__c.getInstance(UserInfo.getOrganizationId()).Client_Secret__c;
            endPoint = Premier_API_Production__c.getInstance(UserInfo.getOrganizationId()).Authentication_Endpoint__c;
        }else{
            system.debug('*** Sandbox ***');
            clientId = Premier_API_Sandbox__c.getInstance(UserInfo.getOrganizationId()).Client_ID__c;
            clientSecret = Premier_API_Sandbox__c.getInstance(UserInfo.getOrganizationId()).Client_Secret__c;
            endPoint = Premier_API_Sandbox__c.getInstance(UserInfo.getOrganizationId()).Authentication_Endpoint__c;
        }
        
        //Define request body with client credentials, client Id and client Secret
        if(clientId != null & clientSecret!= null){
            requestbody = 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id='+clientId+'&client_secret='+clientSecret;
        }
 
        HttpResponse res = getHTTPResponse(true, requestbody, 'POST', '', endPoint);   
        
        system.debug('##New Token Request Submitted '+res.getStatusCode()+' : '+res);
        deserializeResponse resp1 = (deserializeResponse)JSON.deserialize(res.getbody(),deserializeResponse.class);
        return resp1.access_token; 
    }
    @testVisible
    global void processCaseList(){
        String endPoint='';
        
        if ( !runningInASandbox ) {
            system.debug('*** Production ***');
            endPoint = Premier_API_Production__c.getInstance(UserInfo.getOrganizationId()).GOSL_Acceleration_URL__c ;
        }else{
            system.debug('*** Sandbox ***');
            endPoint = Premier_API_Sandbox__c.getInstance(UserInfo.getOrganizationId()).GOSL_Acceleration_URL__c;
            system.debug('endPoint :-'+endPoint);
        }
        
        
        List<Map<String, Object>> caseData = new List<Map<String, Object>>();
        
        for (Case ObjCse : caseList) {
            
            Map<String, Object> objJSON = new Map<String, Object>();

            objJSON.put('RcNumber', ObjCse.PA_RCID__c);
            objJSON.put('FiscalYear', ObjCse.PA_Fiscal_Year__c);
            objJSON.put('FiscalQuarter', ObjCse.PA_Fiscal_Quarter__c);
            objJSON.put('CaseId', ObjCse.Id);
            objJSON.put('CaseStatus', 'Open');
            objJSON.put('CaseNotes', '');
            objJSON.put('CaseCreatedDate', ObjCse.CreatedDate);
            caseData.add(objJSON);
        }
        String jsonString = JSON.serialize(caseData);
        system.debug('###JSON Response==='+JSON.serialize(caseData));   
        
        
        try{   
            HttpResponse response = getHTTPResponse(false, JSON.serialize(caseData), 'POST', premierAPIAccessToken, endPoint);
            
            if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                System.debug('##The status code returned was : ' + response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
                System.debug('*** Response Body when Status 200 *** '+response.getBody());
            }
            else{
                if(response.getStatusCode() == 400){    
                    System.debug('*** Affinity Response Body when status other than 200 & 401 *** '+response.getBody());
                }
            }
            if(response.getStatusCode() == 401) {
                System.debug('Unauthorized : '+ response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
            }
            
            system.debug('##Payload in HTTP:- '+JSON.serialize(caseData));
            System.debug('##Response = '+response.getBody()); 
            System.debug('##Response Status Code = '+response.getStatusCode());
            System.debug('premierAPIAccessToken= '+premierAPIAccessToken);
            
            List<Contact> lstCntct = [SELECT Id, Email FROM Contact WHERE email <> null];
            EmailTemplate et = [SELECT Id, Subject, Body FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name = 'PA Bulk data upload job process Details template'];
            Set<String> toAddresses = new Set<String>{'deepender.singhchouhan@dellteam.com', 'beerendra.mc@dellteam.com', 'mahesh_janagam@dell.com', 'prathmesh.patewar@dellteam.com','naveen.bs@dell.com','vijayalakshmi_muruku@dell.com'};
            
                
                if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                for (Case objCase: CaseList){

                    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                    
                    mail.setTemplateId(et.Id);
                    mail.setToAddresses(new List<String>(toAddresses));
                    mail.setTargetObjectId(lstCntct[0].Id); 
                    mail.setWhatId(objCase.PA_Acceleration_Case_Filter__c);
                    mail.setSenderDisplayName('GOSL Acceleration');
                    mail.setBccSender(false); 
                    mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);  
                    mail.setUseSignature(false);
                    
                    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> allmsg = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
                    allmsg.add(mail);
                    
                    try {
                        Messaging.sendEmail(allmsg,false);
                        return;
                        
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.debug(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
                
            }

            
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            
            System.debug('Error:' + e.getMessage() + 'Line no:' + e.getLineNumber());
        }
        
        
    }    
    
    Public Static HttpResponse getHTTPResponse(Boolean flgAccessToken, String reqBody, String methodType, String accessToken, String endPoint){
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setTimeout(120000);
        req.setMethod(methodType);
        req.setEndpoint(endPoint);
        System.debug('### accessToken : ' + accessToken);
        if(flgAccessToken){//Executes only for the Access Token
            req.setBody(reqBody);
        }else{
            //Executes when the service endpoint is hit
            if(String.isNotBlank(reqBody)){
                req.setBody(reqBody);
            }
            req.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + accessToken);
            req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
            req.setHeader('accept','application/json');
        }
        System.debug('### Request : ' + req);
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        
        return res;
    }
}
```

Test Class

```
@isTest
public class clsPACaseBulkAPIJobMonBatchable_Test {
     
    public static string rtId = [SELECT id from RecordType where name ='GOSL Acceleration'].id;    
    public static User premierAPIIntegrationUser = [SELECT Id, Name,email FROM User WHERE  Name = 'PremierGOSL apiintegration' AND Profile.Name = 'API Integration' AND IsActive = True LIMIT 1];
    private Id recordId;
    private String status;
   
    @testSetup static void testSetupMethod() {
        
        //create data for Premier_API_Token custom setting
       Premier_API_Token__c preAPIToken = new Premier_API_Token__c();
       preAPIToken.Token__c = 'testtoken';
       preAPIToken.Token_Expiry_DT__c = Datetime.now() + 3;
       preAPIToken.Token_Generated_DT__c = Datetime.now() + 5;
       insert preAPIToken;
       
        //create data for Premier API Sandbox  custom setting
       Premier_API_Sandbox__c premierapi = new Premier_API_Sandbox__c();
       premierapi.Affinity_API_URL__c = 'https://test.salesforce.com';
       premierapi.Authentication_Endpoint__c = 'https://test.salesforce.com';
       premierapi.Client_ID__c = 'testclientId';
       premierapi.Client_Secret__c = 'testsecret';
       premierapi.GOSL_Acceleration_URL__c = 'https://test.salesforce.com';
       insert premierapi;
       
        //create data for Premier_API_Production__c  custom setting
       Premier_API_Production__c  premierProdApi = new Premier_API_Production__c();
       premierProdApi.Affinity_API_URL__c = 'https://test.salesforce.com';
       premierProdApi.Authentication_Endpoint__c = 'https://test.salesforce.com';
       premierProdApi.Client_ID__c = 'testclientId';
       premierProdApi.Client_Secret__c = 'testsecret';
       premierProdApi.GOSL_Acceleration_URL__c = 'https://test.salesforce.com';
       insert premierProdApi;
        
       
    
    }
    @isTest
    static void staticValuesTest(){
        Test.startTest();
        boolean bool = clsPAPostCasesToMwBatchable.runningInASandbox;
        string apiToken = clsPAPostCasesToMwBatchable.premierAPIAccessToken;        
        Test.stopTest();
    }
    
     @isTest
    static void ReturnAccessTokenTest(){
        Test.startTest();
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGenerator());
        clsPAPostCasesToMwBatchable.ReturnAccessToken();
        Test.stopTest();
    
    }

    public static testMethod void testExecuteMethod() {
        PA_Acceleration_Case_Filter__c testACF = new PA_Acceleration_Case_Filter__c();
        List<Case> caseList = new List<Case>();
        System.runAs(premierAPIIntegrationUser){          
            testACF.OwnerId = premierAPIIntegrationUser.Id;
            testACF.PA_Total_Records_Processed__c = 5;
            testACF.PA_Status__c = 'Completed';  
            Test.startTest();
            insert testACF; 
            for(Integer i=1; i<=5; i++){
                Case newCase = new Case();
                newCase.RecordTypeId = rtId;
                newCase.Subject = 'Test Case ' + i;
                newCase.Description = 'This is a test case';
                newCase.PA_Acceleration_Case_Filter__c = testACF.Id;
                newCase.Status = 'New';
                newCase.Origin ='Acceleration Integration';
                newCase.Task_Category__c = 'Onboarding';
                newCase.PA_RCIDFiscalData_External_ID__c = 'Test';
                newCase.PA_Offline_Revenue__c = 122324334.56;
                caseList.add(newCase);
            }            
            if(!caseList.isEmpty()){
                insert caseList;            
            }            
        } 
        
        PA_Acceleration_Case_Filter__c  acfRecord = [SELECT Id,PA_Total_Records_Processed__c, Records_Succeeded__c, PA_Records_Failed__c FROM PA_Acceleration_Case_Filter__c WHERE Id = :testACF.Id];
        Case objCS = [SELECT Id, Status, Follow_Up_Date__c FROM Case WHERE RecordTypeId =:rtId AND PA_Acceleration_Case_Filter__c =: acfRecord.Id LIMIT 1];
        string Status = objCS.Status;
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new CalloutMockGOSL(objCS.Id, Status));
        Database.executeBatch(new clsPACaseBulkAPIJobMonitoringBatchable());    
        Test.stopTest();
    }
    
   
        
    
      public class MockHttpResponseGenerator implements HttpCalloutMock {
        
            
            // Implement this interface method
        public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req){
            // Optionally, only send a mock response for a specific endpoint
            // Create a fake response
            HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.setBody('{"Message":"Success"}');
            res.setStatusCode(200);
            return res;
        }
    }
}
```

CalloutMockGOSL

```
public with sharing class CalloutMockGOSL implements HttpCalloutMock {

private Id recordId;
private String Status;

public CalloutMockGOSL(Id recordId, String Status) {
    this.recordId = recordId;
    this.Status = Status;
}

public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
    HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();

    response.setStatusCode(200);
    response.setBody('{"Id": "' + recordId + '", "Status": "' + Status + '"}');

    return response;
}
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please [edit] the question to add the exact detail of the problem you face. Providing a large code dump doesn't help us since we can't try your code directly - it relies on your own custom object model. Make sure to include the exact error message, if there is one. Remember you can enable debug logs to capture more detail from the execution of this code. Take a look at [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) to get some hints around how best to get the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the issue is because test classes don't support chaining - so Batch B never gets called. The way I usually handle that scenario would be to add a check to Batch A finish to see if this is part of a test

```
if (Test.IsRunningTest() == false) {
    Database.executeBatch(cls);
}
```

If yes, don't try to run Batch B. And then to test Batch B, you just need to setup the data as if Batch A has completed and then invoke directly in a test  like you are for Batch A

Answer (score 0):

You have several things you can do to improve test quality:

**For an end-to-end test of Batch A**

- Your test for batch A should assert that an `AsyncApexJob` was created for `Batch B`. This is the best you can do as no batch chaining allowed in testmethods

**For a unit test of Batch A's finish()**

- Construct the batchable, set any stateful variables, and then invoke the `finish()` method directly. This will start batch B and you can then assert that Batch B ran as expected

  - *It is guaranteed that SFDC batchable will execute the `finish()` so you can mock the stateful variables in the batchable*